# SQL Server checking if you have access to a database

Tags: sql-server-2005

Good Morning,

I have connected to my SQL Server 2005 - and have managed to list all of the databases on that server. Now I would like to run a check on each database to see if I have permission to view that database..

How would I go about this?

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to find out all of the names in your DB server:

```
SELECT [name]
  FROM sys.databases;
```

Then, you'll have to run the following command for each database in order to get the permissions:

```
USE databaseName;

SELECT *
  FROM fn_my_permissions(null, 'DATABASE')
```

Comment: Hello - that seems to work great - however, what would I replaced @dbname with?

Comment: @J Harley: My bad.  I forgot to change that to 'DATABASE'.

Comment: If you does not have access to the database, you cannot "use databasename" on it.
Seems like HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME could be an better choice?

Comment: Or even better, use select has_dbaccess(databasename) which gives you 1 or 0, which tells if you are allowed to use the db, then use fn_my_permissions or has_perms_by_name to see if you are allowed to create tables or other stuff in the db.

Answer (score 3):

As neslekkiM has pointed out in the comments of a different answer, you can use this inline when finding out the list of databases:

```
SELECT name, has_dbaccess(name) 
FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by view the database?!

you can use the following query to list all the permissions on current database:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');
```

Comment: Yes that's kind of what I want to do - but maybe for a database you aren't connected to? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at `sys.database_permissions` where I think you can query this information.

See here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx